# How can all characters from excel file be counted?

Tags: excel, vba

I was using the script which I found here : https://excelribbon.tips.net/T008349_Counting_All_Characters.html

It is working as expected however when there are some other objects like pictures, the script returns me the error 438"Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method".
When I deleted the pictures the script was working well again.

Is there an option to put in the script something like "ignore pictures"? Or is there any better type of script to achieve this? I am not good at all at VBA, all help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified approach that may work out a bit better. I think being explicit which Shape Types you want to count is going to be a cleaner way of going about this.

```
Option Explicit

Private Function GetCharacterCount() As Long
    Dim wks          As Worksheet
    Dim rng          As Range
    Dim cell         As Range
    Dim shp          As Shape

    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each shp In wks.Shapes
            'I'd only add the controls I care about here, take a look at the Shape Type options
            If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then GetCharacterCount = GetCharacterCount + shp.TextFrame.Characters.Count
        Next

        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Union(wks.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), wks.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If not rng Is Nothing Then
            For Each cell In rng
                GetCharacterCount = GetCharacterCount + Len(cell.Value)
            Next
        end if
    Next
End Function

Sub CountCharacters()
   Debug.Print GetCharacterCount()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks a lot, this works great. However when I use just a simple file where is a few text in cells and some text in textbox it only counts the characters in the text box unless I use any function for at least one of the cells. Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can add an if-check like the one here ([VBA Code to exclude images png and gif when saving attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593790/vba-code-to-exclude-images-png-and-gif-when-saving-attachments) for "PNG" and "GIF".).

You just have to change the if-check to check for the picture type you're using "JPG" or "JPEG"? Simply match the extension to the if-check by replacing "PNG" or "GIF" with your extension in CAPS.

Add the if-check right above where the error is occurring or better yet, add it above the scope of where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I took the script from your link and modified it. **Now it works**. 
It's far from perfect (there're some cases where it can still crash), but now it supports handling `Shapes` with no `.TextFrame` property:

```
Sub CountCharacters()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim shp As Shape

    Dim bPossibleError As Boolean
    Dim bSkipMe As Boolean

    Dim lTotal As Long
    Dim lTotal2 As Long
    Dim lConstants As Long
    Dim lFormulas As Long
    Dim lFormulaValues As Long
    Dim lTxtBox As Long
    Dim sMsg As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lTotal = 0
    lTotal2 = 0
    lConstants = 0
    lFormulas = 0
    lFormulaValues = 0
    lTxtBox = 0
    bPossibleError = False
    bSkipMe = False
    sMsg = ""

    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Count characters in text boxes
        For Each shp In wks.Shapes
            If TypeName(shp) <> "GroupObject" Then
                On Error GoTo nextShape
                lTxtBox = lTxtBox + shp.TextFrame.Characters.Count
            End If
nextShape:
        Next shp

        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        ' Count characters in cells containing constants
        bPossibleError = True
        Set rng = wks.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If bSkipMe Then
            bSkipMe = False
        Else
            For Each rCell In rng
                lConstants = lConstants + Len(rCell.Value)
            Next rCell
        End If

        ' Count characters in cells containing formulas
        bPossibleError = True
        Set rng = wks.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        If bSkipMe Then
            bSkipMe = False
        Else
            For Each rCell In rng
                lFormulaValues = lFormulaValues + Len(rCell.Value)
                lFormulas = lFormulas + Len(rCell.Formula)
            Next rCell
        End If
    Next wks

    sMsg = Format(lTxtBox, "#,##0") & _
      " Characters in text boxes" & vbCrLf
    sMsg = sMsg & Format(lConstants, "#,##0") & _
      " Characters in constants" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    lTotal = lTxtBox + lConstants

    sMsg = sMsg & Format(lTotal, "#,##0") & _
      " Total characters (as constants)" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    sMsg = sMsg & Format(lFormulaValues, "#,##0") & _
      " Characters in formulas (as values)" & vbCrLf
    sMsg = sMsg & Format(lFormulas, "#,##0") & _
      " Characters in formulas (as formulas)" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    lTotal2 = lTotal + lFormulas
    lTotal = lTotal + lFormulaValues

    sMsg = sMsg & Format(lTotal, "#,##0") & _
      " Total characters (with formulas as values)" & vbCrLf
    sMsg = sMsg & Format(lTotal2, "#,##0") & _
      " Total characters (with formulas as formulas)"

    MsgBox Prompt:=sMsg, Title:="Character count"

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    If bPossibleError And Err.Number = 1004 Then
        bPossibleError = False
        bSkipMe = True
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Resume ExitHandler
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim NoOfChar As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    NoOfChar = 0

    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange '<- Loop all cell in sheet1 used range

        NoOfChar = NoOfChar + Len(cell.Value) '<- Add cell len to NoOfChar

    Next cell

    Debug.Print NoOfChar

End Sub
```